# Two finger scrolling lags on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: touchpad, 20.04, scrolling

Made a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday, I'm dual booting alongside windows 10. It lags when you scroll with two fingers on the touchpad. I don't have such issues on windows as scrolling is very smooth. How can this be fixed? It's a HP probook 640 G2

Comment: Have you checked to see if HP has any linux drivers available for the touch pad?  You may also want to see if the touchpad manufacturer has any drivers.  Once you determine the make/model of the touchpad, I suggest searching for that model number here, as the answer may be hardware-specific.

Comment: HP doesn't. I tried installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` but it just got worse.

Comment: By it got worse I mean the cursor became very slow, tapping the touchpad to click was unresponsive most times so I had to use the left or right click buttons. I eventually removed the driver and things went back to before. I can't find any info concerning the touchpad on HP's website. Running `xinput list` shows `SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad`

Comment: So I checked device manager on windows and I saw two devices `synaptics symbus touchpad` and `hid compliant mouse`

Answer (score 2):

This is what improved responsiveness for two finger scrolling for me (ThinkPad T14 Gen1, Ubuntu 22.04):

Get xinput props for your touchpad:

```sh
$ xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
```

Set scrolling pixel distance:

```sh
$ xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 10
```

The new setting becomes effective immediately.

In my case it was set to 15 and lowering it to 10 significantly improved responsiveness of two finger scrolling. It turned out that values below 10 are not allowed. Could be a different value for your touchpad (I don't know), so you have to try.

Answer (score 0):

It is a linux bug, probably from the kernel with synaptic touchpads, just by putting the 2 fingers the cursor is lagged. This occurs on all existing versions of linux, with xorg-input-synaptics and libinput I checked on all. It is a software problem because in windows the touchpad is fluid.